# Custom length selection menu doesn't work in DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have a webpage which runs the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": '<select class="form-control input-sm m-b-10" style="width:80%">' +
                  '<option value="10">10 Records</option>' +
                  '<option value="20">20 Records</option>' +
                  '<option value="50">50 Records</option>' +
                  '<option value="100">100 Records</option>' +
                  '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
                  '</select>'
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This has been working fine until I put in the following;

```
<div class="block-area" id="custom-select">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 m-b-15">
            <select class="select">
                <optgroup label="Group 1">
                    <option>Option 1</option>
                    <option>Option 2</option>
                    <option>Option 3</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Group 2">
                    <option>Option 4</option>
                    <option>Option 5</option>
                    <option>Option 6</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After testing it seems to be the `<select>` tag specifically which is causing the issue and stopping the JS from running.

I don't understand why though. Could someone please explain what the issue may be?

Comment: Where is your element with the `example` class?

Comment: Is there any errors in your page ? (use firebug or Chrome's console)

Comment: You should add `value` attributes in `option`tags of your second example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the `value`attribute for your `option` tags. Without that attribute the plugin can't know how much rows you want to display.

So update your code :

```
var menu = '<div class="block-area" id="custom-select">'
+'<div class="row">'
+'<div class="col-md-2 m-b-15">'
+'<select class="select">'
+'<optgroup label="Per 10">'
+'<option value="10">10</option>'
+'<option value="20">20</option>'
+'<option value="30">30</option>'
+'</optgroup>'
+'<optgroup label="Per 50">'
+'<option value="50">50</option>'
+'<option value="100">100</option>'
+'</optgroup>'
+'</select>'
+'</div>'
+'</div>'
+'</div>'

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": menu
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fo0yx5mL/)